# CDN and Google font

Tags: cdn, webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm using a new CDN and recently I made a google font for my website menu. Now I activated the CDN, but the "custom font" shall I say is not appearing. All images, files and css are OK. Only this custom font.

I have this in the style.css (I have the fonts stored in my server).

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi Bold';
    src: url('DroidKufi-Bold.eot');
    src: url('DroidKufi-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('DroidKufi-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('DroidKufi-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi Bold';
    src: url('DroidKufi-Bold.ttf');
```

My website is http://www.formulawahad.com // Is there a fix for that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is maybe related to CORS. Your CDN provider need to enable cross-origin resource sharing (CORS). This will set the header to: Access-Control-Allow-Origin “*”. Otherwise is the content rejected.